# Updating or empty a div and then re-populate from a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve is when a database is updated the div that lists the database data is updated without refreshing the page. I have a function that sends a `$get.json` request to a php processing page that returns the data held in the database and displays the returned data in the div, I know this works because the function is called on document ready and the data is displayed in the div. I have tried to empty the div, which I can achieve easily, but when I call the function that would essentially reload the div from the database it will not run.

What I have tried is the following

```
$('#adminResult').empty();
$('#adminResult').listJuniorAdmin();
```

When I run this within my code the `#adminResult` is emptied however the `.listJuniorAdmin();` doesn't seem to work as the div is not repopulated with the database data. If the page is refreshed the div is populated from the `.listJuniorAdmin();` which will show any updates from the database. It's almost as if once the `.empty()` function fires it exits the code. I have also looked at reloading the div with `.load()`but needs html from a php page to work I believe. Can anyone show me how to empty the div and then call my already working function please.

This is my jquery function

```
  listJuniorAdmin: function () {
<!--start of getting and adding the list of junior admin to the junior admin list-->

    $.getJSON('includes/juniorAdminList.php', function(data)    { <!--jason call to juniorAdminList.php processing page-->

        $.each(data, function(key, val) { <!--iterate through the responce from the juniorAdminList.php processing page-->

        var Junior_Admin_ID = val.Junior_Admin_ID; <!--assign each Junior_Admin_ID from the database to the variable Junior_Admin_ID-->
        var Junior_Admin_Name = val.Junior_Admin_Name; <!--assign each Junior_Admin_Name from the database to the variable Junior_Admin_Name-->

//console.log(Junior_Admin_ID); <!--print out Junior_Admin_ID variable in browser console for error checking purposes. Commented out in final code-->
//console.log(Junior_Admin_Name);   <!--print out Junior_Admin_Name variable in browser console for error checking purposes. Commented out in final code-->

$('#adminResult').append('<input id="' + key + '" class="deleteCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="Delete">')
<!--$('#adminDelete').append('<input id="' + key + '" class="deleteCheckBox" type="checkbox">')-->
$('#adminResult').append('<div id="' + key + '" class="list_junior_admin_ID">' + Junior_Admin_ID + '</div>');
<!--$('#adminDelete').append('<div id="' + key + '" class="delete_list_junior_admin_ID">' + Junior_Admin_ID + '</div>');-->
$('#adminResult').append('<div id="' + key + '" class="list_junior_admin_Name">' + Junior_Admin_Name + '</div>');
<!--$('#adminDelete').append('<div id="' + key + '" class="delete_list_junior_admin_Name">' + Junior_Admin_Name + '</div>');-->

        }); <!--end of iterate through the responce from the juniorAdminList.php processing page-->


    }); <!--end of jason call to juniorAdminList.php processing page-->
<!--end of getting and adding the list of junior admin to the junior admin list-->,
    },

<!--        myfunction2: function () -->
   <!-- {-->
   <!-- }-->


});
<!--end of declare listJuniorAdmin function-->
```

This is my html code for the results div

```
<!--start of admin display div-->
<div id="adminDisplay">
<label class="label5">List of Junior Admin</label>

<!--start of admin result div-->
<div id="adminResult"></div>
<!--end of admin result div-->

</div>
<!--end of admin display div-->


<!--start of admin delete div-->
<div id="adminDelete">

<label class="label4">Delete Junior Admin</label>

</div>
<!--end of admin delete div-->


<input type="button" class="button3" id="closeAdmin" value="Close Admin">

</div>
<!--end define admin div-->
```

Comment: why you are calling function `$('#adminResult').listJuniorAdmin();` like this, It should be `this.listJuniorAdmin();`

Comment: @ vinnie: Where would I place that code, I have only used 'this' when I'm getting an attribute of an object

Answer (score 0):

This is simple Literal based programming. See example

```
var myObjectLiteral = {
    myProperty : function(){
         alert('function called');
    }

    //call function inside
     this.myProperty();
}
// calling myProperty method
myObjectLiteral.myProperty();
```

See more example [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript--net-7670)

Comment: I must be really thick, there is no 'this' in that example, I'm not an expert in jquery and to be honest the function I have written works and on document ready it does exactly what I expected it to, in one short line, as I explained I cant seem to get it to run after I used $('#adminResult').empty();, but if I dont use .empty() it will do the update just it doesn't rewrite the data, it adds to the data already there, so I get the whole block duplicated except there is the addition of the new data added to the database

Comment: yes i didn't mention `this` anywhere. See updated answer where to use `this`. I am not saying to remove `$('#adminResult').empty();` you are just calling `listJuniorAdmin()` wrong way thats why its not working

Comment: @vinnie: I do appreciate your trying to help, I havent posted all of the code as I'm using essentially one html page and jquery to manage the function and navigation. This amounts to 700 lines of code, and I know if I posted all of that I will get admonished for it, also a majority of the code  would be superfluous to the problem I am trying to resolve. I have been trying to solve this for over 12 hours now and would accept my tiredness is making me grumpy and irritable.

Comment: ok then just tell me what is your literal name of `listJuniorAdmin()` and where you are calling this function inside your literal or outside

Comment: The listJuniorAdmin is a function as posted in my question, on document ready I call $('#adminResult').listJuniorAdmin(); which populates the adminResult div with the data from the database that is retrieved through the function calling a php processing page that returns the data to the function in json format. I hope that answers your question. Is there any other way that we can converse on this matter other than in stackoverflow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109005/discussion-between-tiny-and-vinie).